# Scope of 'const' for pointers to protect underlying members of struct in C

Tags: c

What is the scope of 'const' in pointer declaration to protect underlying members of a struct?

Here my code explanation:

```
typedef struct {
    int member1;
    int member2;
}tInnerStruct;

typedef struct {
    tInnerStruct *struct1;
    tInnerStruct *struct2;
    tInnerStruct *struct3;
}tContainerStruct;

void function1(const tContainerStruct * ptr)
{
//  L1  |   L2   |  L3         => Up to which level 'const' protects ?
    ptr->struct1->member1 = 5;  // => Why is this legal?
                                //    Shouldn't 'const' protect this?
}
```

Up to which level 'const' qualifier protects underlying members?
Seems evident that

```
ptr->struct1
```

cannot be modified, the same for struct2 and struct3, because are members of the struct marked as const. But all members of struct1, struct2 and struct3 are not affected at all by 'const' modifier?

Comment: I forgot the pointer. Just edited it. Thnks

Comment: As written, this gives you `error: member reference type 'tInnerStruct' is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?`.  If you change it to `.` you get `error: cannot assign to variable 'ptr' with const-qualified type`

Comment: `struct1` is just a pointer. Its target doesn’t belong to `tContainerStruct` and it isn’t a `const` pointer, so…

Comment: Const declares what's const-ptr. That's it.

Comment: `const tContainerStruct *ptr` says that you can't modify the things that `ptr` points at — the `struct1`, `struct2` and `struct3` pointers.  It doesn't say you can't use the `ptr->struct1` pointer to change what it points at.

Comment: `struct1->member1` is not an underlying member of `tContainerStruct` . There is no relationship between a pointer and where it is currently pointing.

Comment: "Why is this legal?" --> because `tInnerStruct *struct1;` is not `const tInnerStruct *struct1;`

Comment: Detail: "all members of struct1, struct2 and struct3 ...." --> `struct1, struct2, struct3` have no members.  They are all pointers.  What they point to has members.

Comment: So if `struct1, struct 2, struct3` were not pointers but just structs inside `tContainerStruct`, would their members be protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` only applies to the portion of the declaration it is modifying.

So:

```
int d;
int * const q = &d;
*q = 3;             /* OK, *q is not const */
q = NULL;           /* ERROR, q is const */
const int * p;
p = &d;             /* OK, p is not const */
*p = 3;             /* ERROR, *p is const */
```

`const`ness does not traverse beyond the immediate object to which it is applied.
For your example, a `const tContainerStruct` would mean that each member of `tContainerStruct` would be `const`. Suppose we defined:

```
typedef struct {
    tInnerStruct * const struct1;
    tInnerStruct * const struct2;
    tInnerStruct * const struct3;
}constant_tContainerStruct;
```

Then `constant_tContainerStruct` would behave like your `const tContainerStruct`. But, since the `const` is applied to the pointer member, it has no affect on the `tInnerStruct` being pointed to, so those objects remain modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, const applies only to the "second level", per se. Only the level to which it is applied.
Consider the following:

```
struct a_s {
   int x;
   const int cx;
};
struct b_s { 
    struct a_s *y;
    const struct a_s *cy;
    struct a_s * const yc;
    const struct a_s * const cyc;
};
struct b_s *b;
b = 1; // ok

b->y = 1; // ok
b->y->x = 1; // ok
b->y->cx = 1; // error, typeof(b->y->cx) = const int

b->cy = 1; // ok, you can modify the pointers value
b->cy->x = 1; // error, b->cy points to a read-only object, you can't modify the memory where the pointer points to
b->cy->cx = 1; // error, typeof(b->y->cx) = const int

b->yc = 1; // error, b->yc is const, the pointers value itself is read-only, but...
b->yc->x = 1; // ok, you can modify the memory where the pointer points to.
b->yc->cx = 1; // error, typeof(b->y->cx) = const int

b->cyc = 1; // error, the pointers value itself is read-only, you can't modify the pointer
b->cyc->x = 1; // error, the memory to which the pointer points is read-only too
b->cyc->cx = 1; // error, typeof(b->y->cx) = const int

const struct b_s *cb;
cb = 1; // ok, there is no const after '*' ;)

cb->y = 1; // error, cb points to read-only object, but
cb->y->x = 1; // ok, the pointer cb->y points to a modifiable memory. 
// The pointer cb->y can't be modified, but the memory to which the pointer points to can be modified
cb->y->cx = 1; // this is always error

cb->cy = 1; // still error
cb->cy->x = 1; // error

cb->yc = 1; // error, not only b points to read-only memory, but the pointer itself is read-only
```

For some reference&reading see [constness section here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer).